# Question body flashes when clicked

Tags: bug

This is something I've encountered a couple of times recently on StackOverflow. The problem might exist on other SE sites as well, but I don't know since I don't visit them as much as SO.

What's happening is that whenever I click somewhere in the body of a question (specifically, when I release the mouse button) the question body blinks/flashes once as if it's being refreshed. Reloading the page appears to resolve the issue. I'm not sure how to reproduce this issue, but it has happened on more than one occasion.

Environment: Windows 10, Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m. Windows 7, Chrome (unknown version).