# Question auto-refresh causes links to fail?

Tags: bug, questions, live-refresh

I've noticed today that questions appear to be auto-refreshing when they're edited, rather than getting the usual "this post has been edited, click to refresh banner".

When this happens, the links below (edit, close, flag) also stop working - instead the question appears to refresh again when you click them.  A full page reload is needed to get them working again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posts flickers if text is selected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333225/posts-flickers-if-text-is-selected); also reported specifically [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333368/question-body-flashes-when-clicked)

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks - yes that sounds the same thing indeed!